# Mongo DB aggrregation on multiple arrays

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to retrieve from my cart items and bundles that are not deleted.
my cart looks like this:

```
{
 "_id": "589474849d7b3f439797faf1",
 "bundles": [{
    "id": "57c98e25298cd0f908021c12",
    "serial": "xxxx",
    "status": ""
 }],
 "items": [{
    "id": "589de9a690d632ccbc10cd64",
    "status": "deleted",
    "quantity": 1,
    "serial": "fffff"
 }]
}
```

What I tried was:

```
[
            {$match: condition},
            {$unwind: {"path": "$items", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true}},
            {$unwind: {"path": "$bundles", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true}},
            {$match: {"items.status": {$ne: "deleted"}}},
            {$match: {"bundles.status": {$ne: "deleted"}}},
            {
                "$group": {
                    "_id": "$_id",
                    currency: {$first: "$currency"},
                    tenant: {$first: "$tenant"},
                    user: {$first: "$user"},
                    "items": {"$addToSet": "$items"},
                    "bundles": {"$addToSet": "$bundles"}
                }
            }
        ];
```

It works fine for all cases except when there is only one deleted item, and multiple bundles. The query return no bundles at all

expected output:

```
{
"_id": "589474849d7b3f439797faf8",

"items": [{
    "id": "589de9a690d632ccbc10cd64",
    "quantity": 1,
    "serial": "fff"

}, {
    "id": "589de9a690d632ccbc10c55",
    "quantity": 1,
    "serial": "xxx"
}],
"bundles": [{
    "id": "57c98e25298cd0f908021c12",
    "serial": "pppp"
}]
}
```

Comment: Hi jamil; can I make a suggestion? Could you [edit] your question to show precisely the expected result i.e. the data structure you are trying to get back from your query?

Comment: thank you I found a solution
now how do I close a question?

Comment: If you post your solution as an answer yourself, then you will be able to Accept it (possibly after a delay), and your question will no longer be on the unanswered list.

Comment: thank you
@Vince Bowdren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh thanks guys I found the solution, filter will do the trick

```
[{
$match: "condition"
}, {
$project: {
    items: {
        $filter: {
            input: "$items",
            as: "item",
            cond: {
                $ne: ["$$item.status", "deleted"]
            }
        }
    },
    bundles: {
        $filter: {
            input: "$bundles",
            as: "bundle",
            cond: {
                $ne: ["$$bundle.status", "deleted"]
            }
        }
    }

}
}]
```